# Voltage Drops to 0 When Load is Connected

Tags: voltage, circuit-analysis, current, voltage-regulator, troubleshooting

[image]

I have put together a simple voltage regulator that uses an LM338 IC and a potentiometer to adjust the voltage. On the output, I also put an inline 3A fuse to protect it from overloading.
[image](the diagram shows a different IC although I did use the LM338)

I am trying to power a light bulb using this power supply rated at 4V and 3A.

When measuring the voltage without load it shows 3.9V, but when I connect it to the light bulb it then drops to 0V. Also connecting an ammeter shows that it is only drawing 0.1A which seems too low.

I am not sure why this is the case and would appreciate any suggestions.

Comment: Are you using LM317 or LM388? your diagram says LM317 and your description says LM388. Are you using 5V input? Is it at 5V when you connect the bulb?

Comment: Hi although the circuit diagram shows an LM317 I did use an LM388 IC which is rated for 5A. The program I was using did not have a LM388 symbol so I just used the other one as a stand-in. The voltage out of the output was 3.9V as stated above. The 5V is simply the PSU that powers the circuit but that voltage is stepped down to 3.9V.

Comment: Do you mean LM338 because LM388 seems to be an audio amplifier

Comment: Sorry yes I meant LM338

Comment: What is the input voltage?

Comment: The input voltage to the IC is 5V which is stepped down to 3.9V

Comment: Let us [continue this discussion in chat](https://chat.stackexchange.com/rooms/145941/discussion-between-sai-and-import-hill).

Comment: What's the maximum current rating on that 5V power supply?

Comment: The maximum current rating is 5A

Comment: Does the lamp light for a while before going out, or is the output 0V immediately after connecting the lamp?

Comment: It is immediate and the light doesn't turn on at all

Comment: FYI, the drop-out voltage at 3A is well over 2V, which means you can't expect even 3V out with a load of 3A. That doesn't explain why you get zero, but you need to be aware of that.

Comment: When you obtain 3.9V, unloaded, what's the resistance of RP1?

Comment: I was getting ~10 ohms although my reading could've been wrong

Answer (score 3, accepted):

With a 5V input, the highest possible "official" output from that voltage regulator is 1.2V (\$V_{REF}=1.2V\$) lower than this, which is 3.8V.

Under load, this value decreases rapidly. At 3A of load, the drop-out voltage exceeds 2V, and you cannot expect more than 3V output, with a 5V input.

You've overestimated this regulator's ability to provide 4V, both in terms of drop-out *and* its internal reference. The only way you can guarantee 4V out from this thing (under load) is if you increase input voltage to 7V or more.

The only reasons (I can think of) that it outputs 3.9V *at all*, with no load, is because it's operating way outside of its specified limits, or it's broken. I don't think it's broken.

You need to study the [datasheet](https://www.ti.com/lit/ds/symlink/lm338.pdf), and learn what this thing can and can't do. In particular, learn how to calculate exactly what resistance RP1 should be, to obtain the exact output you require.

Answer (score 2):

The LM317 is rated to provide only 1A to 1.5A depending on manufacturer.

It can't provide 3A.

It will shut down and you get 0V.

Comment: Hi although the circuit diagram shows an LM317 I did use an LM338 IC which is rated for 5A. The program I was using did not have a LM388 symbol so I just used the other one as a stand-in.